# Is a loan contract valid if a different amount than was stated was borrowed?

Tags: contract-law, borrowing

If there is a contract written that entitles one party (the lender) to give another party (the borrower) X amount of money (e.g., £700) and the lender only gives some fraction of that (e.g., £300) on account of the borrower not requiring the full amount, is the contract invalidated on account of not containing the right amount (or rather the borrower not being given the full amount)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is subject to specific facts and circumstances of the contract wording.

Comment: Technically a lot of questions here a specific to wording.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by invalidated you mean you do not have to pay it back, no it is not invalidated.

The way a loan is supposed to work is that you are given the money and then you could spend it or use the unused portion of the money to pay back the loan.

The $400 that you did not use would technically be considered payment on the loan and you would owe $300.

Comment: Thank you, that is extremely interesting. Apologies if I misused the term "invalidated"

Comment: I am glad you found it interesting. I didn't mean to question your wording. I meant I hoped I interpreted it the way you meant it.